# Sencha cmd returning 'Fashion build exited with code : 2' error while running 'sencha app watch' - what should I do?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

Sencha cmd, extJs 7: Fashion build exited with code : 2

I'm new to ExtJS, I was trying to use sencha cmd to create a project in a  **vagrant linux vm hosted on mac os (m2 chip)**.  But I got errors while doing `sencha app watch`

My steps:

1. fully install sencha cmd + all extensions.
   `./SenchaCmd-7.6.0.87-linux-amd64.sh -Dall=true -q`
2. initial project
   `sencha app init --ext@7.6.0 --classic MyApp`
3. compile development
   `sencha app watch`

```
......
[INF] Writing content to /opt/bip/release/development/MyApp/build/development/MyApp/app.json
/root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.6.0.87/bin/linux-x64/node/node: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
[ERR] 
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Fashion build exited with code : 2
.....
.....
[ERR] /root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.6.0.87/plugin.xml:378: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.6.0.87/ant/build/app/build-impl.xml:253: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.6.0.87/ant/build/app/watch-impl.xml:87: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.6.0.87/ant/build/app/build-impl.xml:292: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.6.0.87/ant/build/app/sass-impl.xml:205: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.6.0.87/ant/build/app/sass-impl.xml:240: com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Fashion build exited with code : 2
```

My env:

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

node : v14.19.0

npm : 6.14.16

java :openjdk version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18 LTS

ruby: ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [aarch64-linux-gnu]

I've also tried installed a macOS version on my local machine and everything's working fine. The error only appeared in the vm env. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: These kind of build errors sometimes indicate errors in the JavaScript code somewhere. Look for `Unterminated quoted string` in the code somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the node that the Sencha cmd bundled with the node that installed in my vm solves my issue:

```bash
cp /usr/bin/node /root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.6.0.87/bin/linux-x64/node
```

Answer (score 0):

Yanguo!

You can run sencha app build too, so it can show you more details about the error;

If the error persists you may have to make a double check in the code, this error. As i'm seeing. Your App.json file is with a quoted string error.

It says: `Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`. If you open the file it may show you an error in your editor or IDE.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This project is an example project I initialise using Sencha cmd. The app.json file was generated automatically and I didn't change anything inside of it. The same steps on my host machine has no errors

Comment: I see, I'm currently using modern toolkit with open tooling and sometimes in the app generating process some files doesn't load some necessary files. In your case, using cmd the same can happen.

One thing you can try is `sencha app clean; sencha app build` in the terminal.

Comment: Maybe you can find a solution in cmd's documentation. Here's a link

https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.6.0/guides/cli_reference.html

Try to look at it, it's pretty complete.